# Using Tailwind opacity classes with CSS variables

Tags: tailwind-css

If I do this:

```
:root {
    --theme-colour: theme('colors.blue.500/20');
}
```

the output is `rgb(59 130 246 / 20)` instead of `rgb(59, 130, 246, .2)` which doesn't produce any change in opacity.

Is there any way around that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're working with a scale of `0` to `100`, consider using `0.2` after the slash as an equivalent in a scale of `0` to `1`:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.3.3"></script>

<div class="bg-[color:--theme-colour] w-10 h-10"></div>
<div class="bg-blue-500 w-10 h-10"></div>

<style type="text/tailwindcss">
:root {
  --theme-colour: theme('colors.blue.500/0.2');
}
</style>
```